# UnicodeEncodeError error when I redirect the output of a Python script into file

Tags: python, bash, unicode

I am writing a Python script to gather statistics on a directory that contains a very large number of files. The script itself works correctly by printing text into the terminal. I get no error. However, when I redirect the output stream into file in bash, I get the error below:

```
python file_paths_processing.py -l 100 --dir-path "F:/bigdirectory" > dump.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My_Designs\Python\myscripts\file_paths.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\My_Designs\Python\myscripts\file_paths.py", line 39, in main
    print("{:>4}  {}".format(len(file), file))
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 45-54: character maps to <undefined>
```

From what I understand, there are some files somewhere that contain unicode characters in their name. This is certainly the cause behind the fault. But what is the correct way to fix this? If the script can write into the terminal without error, then why not just redirect it into a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the standard output is a text stream(`io.TextIOWrapper`) and its default encoding on a Windows console depends on whether you are redirecting or not.(If you are interested on the history, see [PEP 528](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/).) You can inspect that like the following example.

```
import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding, file=sys.stderr)
```

In my environment, this prints `utf-8` if it's not redirected and `cp1252` if it's redirected.

So, you should change the encoding of the standard output. There are many possible methods. I'll give two.

To do that inside Python, do like this.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

To do that outside Python, do like this, since you are using Bash.

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Comment: What is cp1252?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Relationship_to_Unicode).